# How can I fit a picture in LaTeX (regarding to being center and also fit height and its width)?

Tags: diagrams

I try to put my picture in a page, my picture is a little bit large.
I try this way, it does not give me the best answer, some part of the image is cut. I also try `[width=\0.5]` or `[scale=\0.6]` or many other numbers instead of them, but no good answer. Does anyone know what do exactly `width=\linewidth` and `\columnwidth` and `height-0.35\textheight` do?

```latex
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{center}
        \hfill\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=0.35\textheight]{axe/11}\hspace*{\fill}  %it is suggested to using scale to zoom figures without distortion
    \end{center}
    \caption{The overview of three tanks connect to each other \cite{xie1999strong}.}
    \label{fig:tank}
\end{figure}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Your figure most likely contains some whitespace around it. Use `\fbox{\includegraphics[..]{...}}` to see what the space around it is.

Answer (score 1):

First, as advised by [@Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/513530/how-can-i-fit-a-picture-in-latex-regarding-to-being-center-and-also-fit-height#comment1298629_513530), make sure your picture has minimal white (useless) space around it.

Then a standard

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img/myfigure.jpg}
\caption{blablabla}
\end{figure}
```

should do the trick.

If you want more tuning, you can check `\resizebox{}{}{}`. For instance:

```
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\includegraphics[scale=1]{img/myfigure.jpg}
}
```

Comment: Your last suggestion is similar yet inferior to the first. Also, you have some spurious spaces in the usage.

Comment: `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{img/myfigure.jpg}` is sometimes more suitable